# Visualize Pathfinding Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame, grid, path-finding

I was doing a pathfinding visualizer in pygame and I pretty much finished but there's still one thing that I do not like about the algorithm part of it and it's the fact that when you press the visualize algorithm button it shows you the shortest path in yellow and all of the nodes the algorithm has visited ever in light blue but it shows you instantaneously and I want it to color the nodes accordingly step by step to actually reach the effect of visualizing (like in here https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/#), I tried to write some code in the function that seemed like it would have worked as intended but it didn't, here is the code:

```
# Breadth First Search Algorithm
def bfs(graph, start, goal):
    explored = []

    # Queue for traversing the
    # graph in the BFS
    queue = [[start]]

    # If the desired node is
    # reached
    if start == goal:
        return

    # Loop to traverse the graph
    # with the help of the queue

    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        y, x = node
        # Codition to check if the
        # current node is not visited

        if node not in explored and nodes_rows[x][y].color is not BLACK:

            nodes_rows[x][y].color = LIGHT_BLUE
            neighbours = graph[node]

            # Loop to iterate over the
            # neighbours of the node
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

                # Condition to check if the
                # neighbour node is the goal
                if neighbour == goal:
                    new_path.remove(start)
                    new_path.remove(goal)
                    return new_path

            explored.append(node)

    return None
```

The `nodes_rows[x][y].color == color_name` is the code that is responsible for coloring nodes on the grid which is represented by a dictionary(I provided it so it's gonna be easier for you to understand how coloring works in general in my program). The problem with that implementation is when I do add the coloring part at if statement to color all the neighbors it does it instantly on the grid without showing a kind of an animation that shows the coloring process node by node, my question is can I do it so it colors them each iteration rather than all at once by adding something to this code and not writing a new one and if I do need to write a new one that what is the instructions how can I do so?

Here is what I mean by coloring all at once like it does for now:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772816508015083552/832303260911272046/PowerPoint_-_1_2021-04-15_20-13-35_Trim.mp4

Edit:

```
try:
    while True:
        if not ticks or pygame.time.get_ticks() - ticks >= 500:
           ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
           nodes = next(algorithm)
           if nodes_rows[nodes[-1][1]][nodes[-1][0]].color != BLUE:
              nodes_rows[nodes[-1][1]][nodes[-1][0]].color = LIGHT_BLUE
              pygame.display.update()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Tried doing it with yield and if I print it it does yield a list every half a second with a new explored node at the end like intended but it updates it all at once after waiting total amount of ticks I tried playing with the indent of display.update() but didn't work either I don't even know what to do at this point

Thanks to everyone contributing to help <3

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] so it's possible to assist you.

Comment: It's probably better to implement BFS as a class with a `step` function where `explored` is an attribute that you can check after each step.  The `step` function would of course move the solution forward by one step. Repeat `step`, get `explored`, draw explored nodes until solution is found.  That said... you might be able to achieve the same effect by turning your `bfs` function into a generator and yielding `explored` at the end of each while-loop iteration.

Comment: @LPR wait how can I turn it into a generator I never used yield before

Comment: @Irkl1_ Two things to check.  1. Add a print statement inside your if-statement to make sure the if-statement isn't always False.  2. Draw the new nodes to the surface before calling pygame.display.update(), right now the update might be working prorperlly... it just has nothing to update, because nothing was drawn on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, here is a simple example of a generator to help you grasp the idea.

```py
def counter(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i
c = counter(3)
```

```
In: next(c)
Out: 0
In: next(c)
Out: 1
In: next(c)
Out: 2
```

What's happening is that every time you call `next`, the function will continue to run until it reaches the next `yield`, at which point it will return the yielded value.

---

It will also remember where it left off, so the next time you call next, the function will continue where it left off.

---

In your application, this could be used to `yield` the list of explored locations, then draw those locations in whatever color you like, call `next(bfs)` to step forward and yield the next list of explored locations, and so on until of course you find the solution and run out of items to yield.

---

One more example, perhaps a little more closely related to what you are trying to do:

```py
def make_path():
    path = []
    
    i = 0
    while True:
        path.append(i)
        i += 1
        yield path
        
c = make_path()

for _ in range(6):
    print(next(c))
```

```
Out: [0]
     [0, 1]
     [0, 1, 2]
     [0, 1, 2, 3]
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I did it now every 0.5 second it yields the explored list but it still updates all at once after waiting the total amount of ticks instead of step by step the second if is just so it wont draw over start node I added the code I used in the original question @LPR

Comment: Never mind I got it man without your help of telling me how to use a generator in my case I couldn't do it take my reputation @LPR

Comment: So it works now? Congrats and thanks for the reputation! That was a nice surprise.

Comment: yeah it works like in the link now with more of an animation look to it thanks man

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that you do not update the canvas in your `while queue` loop.

the program will execute your bfs algorithm and then it will update the canvas.

i honestly don't use pygame very regularly, but i think to force the canvas to repaint you need to stick a `pygame.display.update()` inside your while loop.

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't work although I did it, can you maybe show me where do I need to put it and I'll test it (I tried everywhere btw maybe I'm dumb)

Comment: basically every time you update the colors of your grid, the program should redraw the canvas to actully show the changes, otherwise it will only update when you already finished computing the path.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame is not my forte but, I think there are some missing things in your project:

**1.- You don't really control when colors are shown on your screen.** This can be achieved with this:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

Documentation: https://devdocs.io/pygame/ref/display#pygame.display.update

Usually when working with graphics, you add a color, and when then next screen painting update comes you see it, what you must do is to force the painting so you can animate safely.

**2.- Coloring animations are not being done by default.**
I couldn't help noticing this in your initial question: "it does it instantly on the grid without showing a kind of an animation that shows the coloring process node by node". If you want an animation like the example linked above (Pathfinding visualizer), I'm afraid you have to do it manually. Try creating a test with a white square and start painting growing circles inside interpolating colors, until you reach the walls and paint the full square. This should be similar to what are you trying to accomplish.

**3.- Perhaps you should add some stops when you are animating your canvas.**
The refresh rate of your hardware is way too faster than your human eye.
To properly see a coloring animation you should try adding execution stops, when interpolating colors.

```
nodes_rows[x][y].color = Color(r, g, b)  # Start with a color and interpolate incrementing or decrementing r, g and b until your reach a final color.

pygame.display.update()  # Update your screen

pygame.time.wait(1000)  # In milliseconds, add some time wait so screen can be painted, if time is long enough perhaps screen updates meanwhile and you do not need to update the screen.
```

**4.- (Optional) Parallel painting: Using threads.**
If this does not work right for you, add threads.
As I stated before, pygame is not my forte, but consider adding threads to animate each square color. I've found a post here explaining this.

[using threading in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519420/using-threading-in-pygame)

I hope this helps you and have a happy coding experience! :D